# Setting Layer rendering Blending Mode of Feature using Python

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to set the blending mode of a layer like on the picture, Darken on Feature, not on layer, with Python.

[image]

Here is the code that i used to modify the "Layer" Blending mode.

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
target_field = 'delta_t'
myRangeList = []
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
myRange = QgsRendererRange(0, 10.0, symbol, '0 a 10')
myRangeList.append(myRange)
myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(target_field, myRangeList)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Custom)
layer.setRenderer(myRenderer)
layer.setBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Darken)
```

How can i modify the "Feature" Blending Mode on "Darken"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need modify the "Feature" Blending Mode on "Darken" use this:

```
layer.setFeatureBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Darken)
```